# MySQL: "error in your SQL syntax ... near key ..."?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I found one very cool scirpt for lost password but this row is making me problems

```
$r = mysql_query('INSERT INTO `keys` (username,key, vreme) VALUES ("'.$user.'", "'.$acckey.'", "'.$keyexp.'"') or die(mysql_error());
```

error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, vreme) VALUES ("123123", "1ed2f5100a26298a55b2935cbea7d4a0", "1337991670"' at line 1
```

Comment: I would say "building an SQL string containing values". See the tail of [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com). (All this aside, try your queries in a CLI, as this sort of issue -- reserved words --  is easy to find. I have distilled the error message and put it in the title for you.)

Comment: @pst: you cannot be sure how `$user` and other vars have been processed before. It becomes annoying to read about probable sql injections in every single topic (especially in ones that most likely don't have any issues, like this one)

Comment: @zerkms It doesn't matter to me/I don't care: Manual string building -> too much work and too easy to get wrong. *Easy* consistency and repeatability make for tidy code.

Comment: @pst: but you know - your reference to a bobby-tables here is **totally** irrelevant. The question is about syntax error, not about best practices. He doesn't know basic things, and you've start talking about rocket science.

Comment: @pst: talking about bobby tables is indeed irrelevant here. There's no way you can say that query is vulnerable. You should mention it only when it is obvious from the code.

Comment: @itachi I can only hope that someone, somewhere, will read that link and the world will become a better-coded place because of it. Perhaps even the author of this post.

Answer (score 10):

`KEY` is a [Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  As documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html):

> If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you *must* quote it whenever you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.)
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`` ` ``”):
>
> ```sql
> mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
> ```
>
> If the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks:
>
> ```sql
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
> mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> ```

Therefore:

```php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `keys` (username, `key`, vreme) VALUES ('$user', '$acckey', '$keyexp') ")
```

Answer (score 5):

`key` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) - enclose it in backticks

```
`key`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $r = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `keys` (username,`key`,vreme) VALUES ('$user', '$acckey','$keyexp')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thank you all (:

Answer (score 1):

also remove the double quotes within the query and encapsulate the query within double instead of single quotes.

use single quotes in the query to encapsulate values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$r = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `keys` (username,key,vreme) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$acckey."','".$keyexp."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Stil the same i will go to bed now and tomorow will try again.

Comment: @Благовест Тодоров: try again **what**? I've given the answer an hour ago

Comment: well then zerkms is right. @zerkms I thought your answer meant to use reserved keywords put backticks around it. I never used reserved keywords for table names though so I dont know. The query itself was bad too so I fixed that

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing a single quote at the end of your query between the last close bracket and semi-colon?

Comment: I think that single quote is actually just before the next-to-last close bracket, which I believe is correct, since that's where the query ends.